# jquery - callbacks 101

Tags: jquery

Before I perform some json and disable a button, I simply want to enable other buttons that may have been previously disabled. I think it's related to callbacks which I apparently still don't get. In the code below, the clicked button does not become disabled prior to running the getJSON.

```
$(".btnUseProduct").live("click", function(e) {

    var clickedId = $(this).attr('id');
    var provisioning_id = clickedId.split("^")[0];
    var entity_id = clickedId.split("^")[1];
    var entity = clickedId.split("^")[2];

    showUseButtons(function(){        

               $(this).attr({'disabled':'disabled','value':'Used'}); //doesn't work
               $.getJSON("/chinabuy-new/cfcs/services.cfc?method=update_provisioning&returnformat=json&queryformat=column",{"provisioning_id":provisioning_id,"entity_id":entity_id},function(res,code){                        
               });
        });
    e.preventDefault();
});

function showUseButtons() {
    $(".btnUseProduct").each(function(e) {
        $(this).attr({'disabled':'disabled','value':'Used'});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A callback is a function you pass to another function. That other function you pass it to must call it - otherwise it's useless.

```
function someFunctionThatCallsBack(someCallbackFunction) {
  // do something
  someCallbackFunction(); // calls the callback function
}
```

Above, you are passing a function to `showUseButtons` - but that function just ignores it. It won't be called so whatever you put in there won't do anything.

Perhaps you meant something like the following?

```
function showUseButtons(callback) {
    $(".btnUseProduct").each(function(e) {
        $(this).attr({disabled: true, value:'Used'});
    });
    callback();
}
```

Further, inside a function the context changes (i.e. the value of `this` is different). So you'll need to alter your code somewhat as well:

```
    var _this = this; // save the context - the clicked DOM element
    showUseButtons(function(){        
           $(_this).attr({disabled:true, value:'Used'}); //doesn't work
           $.getJSON("/chinabuy-new/cfcs/services.cfc?method=update_provisioning&returnformat=json&queryformat=column",{"provisioning_id":provisioning_id,"entity_id":entity_id},function(res,code){                        
           });
    });
```

Comment: This works to a degree. But I have two buttons that are both disabling. Only the clicked one should disable. 
Button 1 (clicked): <input id="223^9^products" class="btnUseProduct" type="button" value="Use">
Button 2 (not clicked): <input id="224^9^products" class="btnUseProduct" type="button" value="Use">

Comment: Wait...I think I see what's going on...hang on..Oh, I thought I found the problem but no. The showUseButtons function should be showing not hiding so I changed that. However, on click, the disable is not working.

Comment: @Paul: DOM element id's shouldn't start with a number (that's invalid HTML), and shouldn't contain '^'.

Comment: The clicked button still doesn't disable after those issues are attended to.

Comment: @Paul: your argument to 'attr' should not have quotes around the first item either - I'll edit.

Answer (score -1):

Try This...

```
    $(".btnUseProduct").live("click", function(e) {

        var clickedId = $(this).attr('id');
        var provisioning_id = clickedId.split("^")[0];
        var entity_id = clickedId.split("^")[1];
        var entity = clickedId.split("^")[2];

        showUseButtons(function(){        

                   $(this).attr({'disabled':'disabled','value':'Used'}); //doesn't work
                   $.getJSON("/chinabuy-new/cfcs/services.cfc?method=update_provisioning&returnformat=json&queryformat=column",{"provisioning_id":provisioning_id,"entity_id":entity_id},function(res,code){              
         //give class name common for all buttons and make all to hide 
         $("input.button_class_names").css({'visibility' : 'visible'});
   //make ur pressed button visible like this         
 clickedId.css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
                   });
            });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    function showUseButtons() {
        $(".btnUseProduct").each(function(e) {
            $(this).attr({'disabled':'disabled','value':'Used'});
        });
    }
```